# Comparison of MariaDB Indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I'm using [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) and I'm starting to research indexes as there is one table in particular that runs queries noticeably longer as it's populated with 1,249,848 rows. Almost every table (with the reasonable exceptions) have a primary key; that was pretty straight forward. I came across [Socratica's SQL Index](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsG1XaZEa78) video which is a fantastic watch for those with limited SQL experience in general though unfortunately she failed to clarify which type of index one should use.

HeidiSQL allows the creation of `primary`, `key`, `unique`, `fulltext` and `spatial` indexes, at least with MariaDB and I've been exclusively using MariaDB for the past few years. The table I plan to add a couple of indexes are for the `date` and `engine` columns for my spider log table. I use `DATETIME` and `VARCHAR()` for those respective columns so I have an idea of which types of indexes I want to use though I would very much appreciate a comparison of the indexes with suggestions. The manual covers *what* the indexes do though don't quite seem to cover the contrast of which sets of data they are most appropriate for in comparison to each other index.

Comment: usually when talking about indexing data in a table, you mean simple `key` indexes. The other ones are for special purposes.

Comment: Choosing the right indexes depends on the specific queries for which you want to optimize. You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: Or...  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql .  You probably want `KEY` (aka `INDEX`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be one **`primary`** key on each table, and you should always have one defined. The table data (on disk) will be stored in a way that searching for the primary key is very fast. (called [Clustered Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html))

In most applications, the primary key is an [`auto_increment`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/auto_increment/) [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).
But you might also choose a [*natural* primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key), that is a unique identifier already occuring in your data like serial numbers, MAC addresses, social insurance numbers, ...

**Searching in the primary key is the fastest way to retrieve data, but there can only be one.**

When talking about indexing to speedup searches, people usually mean simple `KEY`s, also called "secondary keys".

For many use cases, it is useful to create a "[covering index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/#covering-indexes)" that contains more than one attribute. 
i.e. `KEY(lastname, surname)` speeds up a query like 
`WHERE lastname="Anderson" AND firstname="Thomas"`
as well as 

`WHERE lastname="Anderson"`
***but not***

`WHERE firstname="Thomas"`

**It is very important to know what queries your application is executing the most and design your indexes for these:**

Not every query can effectively use an index, not all indexes are useful, and under high write loads, it's better to have a few good ones than many poor ones.

Indexes are write expensive: every update on a row means also an update to *each* individual index!

---

The other types are special:

**`unique`** keys ensure that only a single row can hold the same value for an attribute. This is usually used to enforce business rules like "e-mail addresses of accounts must be unique"/"only one account per e-mail".

**`fulltext`** can only be applied to `TEXT` columns and is actually a mini search engine embedded in the database. You can use `AND` and `OR` conditions, wildcards with the special `MATCH` operator for text search.

and **`spatial`** is for coordinate systems / geometry and cannot be used for anything else.

Comment: Got it working and my statistics page no longer requires 20 seconds to load. I appreciate the details here and I'm absolutely certain that I'll be working with indexes on an increasing basis over the next few years. :-)